# API for admin section django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF hence I wish to know that:
http://x.x.x.x:8000/Admin => admin interface for Django Rest Framework. can this be accessed by using API for authenticated users?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't access it throw APIs However, you can create CRUD operations to Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete the table data via `ModelViewSet` or `APIView`.